# O and Ö order as same character with ORDER in Zend_Db

Tags: mysql, sql, zend-framework, zend-db

When I pick up objects from the database and run the Zend magic function -> Order (), or as plain SQL, for example, title, and those containing Swedish characters as åäö so interpreted them as aao. It comes with the wrong sort, either a or o when it really should be ordered last.

Anyone got a clue how to solve this? Have looked like an idiot with no result.

**Edit:** The collation of the database is utf8_unicode_ci and the encoding is utf8. I have tried to change to utf8_swedish_ci but with no success. And I'm afraid I need to have the utf8 left or do I not any choice there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your MySQL database set up to use the proper collation? I think by default it's set to the Swedish collation `latin1_swedish_ci`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-we-sets.html

But if it's been changed to something else (like `latin1`) it might order the accented characters differently.

There are instructions on how to specify which collation to use for a particular DB, column, or table here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-syntax.html

**Edit:** The Swedish collation is what you want: http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.latin1_swedish_ci.html but you are likely using the general one: http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.latin1_general_ci.html

Comment: +1 I misread at first, sorry. This is exactly what he needs. The only thing worth noting is that runtime conversion of collations is slow. For large data sets, it can be feasible to create a separate, `latin1_swedish_ci` collated column for ordering.

Comment: It was simple as that! I just have to change to collation of the columns to latin1_swedish_ci and then it starts working exactly as I wanted. A bit a shame I didn't solved of my own. Thx for fast response.